# How to model linearly this complex piecewise objective function?

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, integer-programming

I want to model linearly the following situation : my objective function $f(q)$ should be like this :

$f(q)=A\cdot q+B\cdot x$ if $x=1, \gamma=0, \delta=0$

$f(q)=A' \cdot q+B'\cdot x$ if $x=1, \gamma=1, \delta=0$

$f(q)=A'' \cdot q+B''\cdot x$ if $x=1, \gamma=0, \delta=1$

$x,\delta, \gamma$ are binary variables and when $x=0$, $\delta=0,\gamma=0$ but the reverse is not true.

$A,A',A", B,B',B"$ are constants.

Thanks for help

Comment: What is $f$ when $x=0$?

Comment: @Matthew Conroy when  $x=0$, $q=0$ automatically  (it is fixed by other contraints) and so $f $ should be nul

Comment: Okay. And what happens if x=1, $\gamma=1$ and $\delta=1$?

Comment: @MatthewConroy It can't happen. There are some constraints that do not allow this configuration

Comment: @MatthewConroy, so do you have any other idea ?  I guess your answer was a good start, the only challenge is how to make it with Cplex, which I guess is not impossible

Comment: No, I'm pretty much out of ideas on this.  I don't see why it should be possible, but I'm not really an LP expert. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your exact requirements aren't clear to me, but it seems like what you want is to model union of polyhedra using mixed-integer linear programming. A good reference for this is [this review paper by Vielma](http://www.mit.edu/~jvielma/publications/Mixed-Integer-Linear-Programming-Formulation-Techniques.pdf). Section 2 of the above paper motivates modeling piecewise linear functions using mixed-integer linear programming, and Section 5 of this paper provides a formal mathematical treatment. Imposing any other logical conditions on the binary variables should be doable using standard mixed-integer linear programming techniques.